# Sharepoint Migration of DB from one server to another server

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, content-database

we have a SharePoint 2010 production farm consists of 2 servers 1 server(App+ WFE) and 1 DB(sQL2008) server .

we would like to move the existing Databases from old server to new database server(Later decomission the old DB server)

As part of this, DB team has done backup and restore of all DBS( content DBS, config Db and service application DBS) to new server. Now I want to point the SharePoint farm to new database server which means detach all the existing DBS old server and point the databases to new server.

Could you please help advise the steps to perform to achieve this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

MSFT outline step by step procedure for moving the database from one server to other. Couple of things you already performed. But here are steps:

1. Stop following services on the SharePoint server (as you have one server for SP).

   - SharePoint 2010 Administration
   - SharePoint 2010 Timer
   - SharePoint 2010 Tracing
   - SharePoint 2010 User Code Host
   - SharePoint 2010 VSS Writer
   - SharePoint Foundation Search V4
   - World Wide Web Publishing Service
   - SharePoint Server Search 14
   - Web Analytics Data Processing Service
   - Web Analytics Web Service
2. Now move the database from existing SQL server to New servers.
3. Set the permission on the new SQL server for the SharePoint accounts.
4. Now you have to create a new SQL alias, which will point to new server.

   - Start SQL Server Configuration Manager. On the Start menu, point to All Programs, point to Microsoft SQL Server 2008, point to Configuration Tools, and then click SQL Server Configuration Manager.
   - Expand SQL Native Client Configuration, right-click Aliases, and then click New Alias.
   - In the Alias Name field, enter the name of the original SQL Server instance, for Protocol, verify that TCP/IP is selected, for Server, enter the name of the new server that is hosting the SharePoint Server 2010 databases, and then click OK.

     5. Now start all the SharePoint services.

Read more here: [Move all databases (SharePoint Server 2010)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512725(v=office.14).aspx#Alias)

Comment: I guess we cannot use  SQL alias  procedure as we are going to decommission the existing server . please suggest if it works or any alternate approach

Comment: thats fine, even you decommission the existing  sql server. When SharePoint try to connect existing SQL server, Alias will redirect it to the new server. It will not check existing server.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add a small hint to Waqas perfect guide for moving to a new SQL-Server:

Please be aware that SharePoint 2010 only Supports SQL-Server Versions 2005, 2008, 2008 R2 and 2012. Newer Versions (2014, 2016) are not supported.